# Classify does not work with my training set

Tags: machine-learning

I tried using `Classify`. It gives the wrong answer even for training data.

```
c = Classify[trainingset];
c[13]
```

> ```
> "T"
> ```

when the training set itself says "F".

```
 trainingset := 
   {1 -> "F", 2 -> "T", 3 -> "F", 4 -> "T", 5 -> "F", 6 -> "T", 7 -> "F", 
    8 -> "T", 9 -> "F", 10 -> "T", 11 -> "F", 12 -> "T", 13 -> "F", 14 -> "T", 
    15 -> "F", 16 -> "T"}
```

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting

Comment: It gives the wrong  answer for TRAINING data!

Comment: A classifier generates some classification based on a training set. It does not mean that it classifies all points of the training data perfectly. 

Note : you can get a bit more insight: `c[13, "Probabilities"]`: `<|"F" -> 0.455556, "T" -> 0.544444|>`.

You might want to play with the `Method`.

Comment: Thanks for this

Answer (score 2):

Up to the @anderstood's advice, the command

```
 trainingset = {1 -> "F", 2 -> "T", 3 -> "F", 4 -> "T", 5 -> "F",6 
 -> "T", 7 -> "F", 8 -> "T", 9 -> "F", 10 -> "T", 11 -> "F", 12 -> 
 "T", 13 -> "F", 14 -> "T", 15 -> "F", 16 -> "T"};
c = Classify[trainingset, Method -> "SupportVectorMachine"]
```

does the job, outputting

```
c[13]
(*F*)
```

and

```
c[13,"Probabilities"]
(*<|"F" -> 0.965753, "T" -> 0.0342467|>*)
```